Optimal Inventory with Fixed Order Sizes (e.g. multiples of 10)
I'm interested in dynamic optimal inventory models where orders must come in multiples of some fixed amount, such as 10 units. In such a case, one might ideally order, say, 18 units at some point but must instead choose 10 or 20.
Can someone point me to a basic model of this? I am new to this area, and just started reading the textbook of Snyder and Shen.

Could you elaborate more on this? Like, write some TeX model, or at least a piece of it, or even the list of variables?
